# Dynamically create variables in loop

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, loops, dynamic

I am trying to create a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < [tabNumbers count]; i++) 
{
    UIViewController *viewController;
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]  init];
    viewController.title = [tabNumbers objectAtIndex:i];
    viewController = [tabNumbers objectAtIndex:1];

    [viewControllersList addObject:viewController];
    [viewController release];
}
```

But the problem is that when I add view the array I get a bunch of view controllers with random names.

Rather than

```
UIViewController *viewController;
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
UIViewControlller *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Controller",[tabNumbers objectAtIndex:i]]
```

But this doesn't work

The reason being, is that once I have created the views in the loop, I am then looking to create a tab bar with each view as a tab and then each tab calls its own view controller

I can't call the view controllers at the moment as I don't know what the random number is that will be generated each time.

Thanks

Bob

Wow - two fantastic and prompt responses.

Unfortunately I am pretty new to Xcode and am slow on the uptake. I thought if I posted the full code it may help in trying to explain what I am trying to do.

So the idea is that the user can add, delete, move or rename tab bar items as they see fit.

The point that I have got to is that I can add the tab bar items, but am unable to get the tab bar items to create the new tables.

I know the code is correct to make the tab bar items - I can add as many tab bar items as I want. 
I know that if I only draw one tab bar item that I can get the table to draw

But what I can't do is get multiple tab bar items each to draw a table.

I thought that the best way was to dynamically name the view controller, which you guys have shown me is not possible.

So the next thought was to try and get it from the array, but given that the array will also change depending on what the user makes the tab bar name, I can't see how this can work.

Any suggestions?

Please if possible, include some snippets of code - I am beginning to understand the code when I read it, but I don't understand the definitions that explain (e.g. a tag for the view controller)

Thanks

Bob

```
- (void)showTabBar 
{
GuidelinesAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (GuidelinesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *viewControllersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *tabItemsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:tabNumbers forKeys:tabNumbers];
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

UIViewController *viewController;
for (int i = 0; i < [tabNumbers count]; i++) 
{
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]  init];
    viewController.title = [tabNumbers objectAtIndex:i];
    [viewControllersList addObject:viewController];
    [viewController release];
}

AppDelegate.tabItemsDict = tabItemsDict;
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllersList animated:YES];

for (NSString *s in viewControllersList)
{
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];        
    NSMutableDictionary *tabTableStructureDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
    AppDelegate.tabTableStructureDict = tabTableStructureDict;

    UINavigationController *bNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.navigationController = bNavigationController;
    [self.view addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    [bNavigationController release];
    [rootViewController release];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ways that might solve this for you...

First off, forget the idea of giving the view controllers a strong reference with a random name, this is not necessary.

UIView has a tag property, this is meant for identifying views. Assign the tag property to the view as you create it and add it to the array. You can then obtain that view again knowing the tag number by filtering on the array or iterating through it.

Another way is to use a dictionary where your key is the view's number and the value is the view itself. So this way you can obtain the view by fetching the value using the key.

Another, arrays are ordered, as you add items to them the order remains the same unless you explicitly modify it, adding an item to a mutable array will place that item at the end, so inherently you know which view is which since you know when you added them to the array.

Comment: So, I after the comments I received about not being able to do what I wanted, I pretty much gave up on what I was trying to do and went and restructured the project from the beginning. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but what you *can* do is to store the references in a dictionary, and use it elsewhere, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *controllers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i = 0; i < [tabNumbers count]; i++) 
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]  init];
    viewController.title = [tabNumbers objectAtIndex:i];
    [controllers setValue:viewController forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Comment: So, I after the comments I received about not being able to do what I wanted, I pretty much gave up on what I was trying to do and went and restructured the project from the beginning. Thanks for your help